# How to add video file at the startup of App in Android Programming?

Tags: android

I need to add video file whenever I start App showing details. So I need help for that. I need to know how to write a code for that.

Answer (score 2):

save your video file in `raw` folder

give your video file name in

```
path="android.resource://yourpackagename/"+R.raw.yourvideofilename;
```

see the below class

```
public class HomeVideo extends Activity{
private VideoView videoView;
 String extStorageDirectory;
 protected static final int PLAY = 0x101; 
 protected static final int STOP = 0x102; 
 protected static final int PAUSE = 0x103; 
 int State; 
 private String current;

 private String path ;
 private VideoView mVideoView;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);
     setContentView(R.layout.homevideo);
     path="android.resource://yourpackagename/"+R.raw.yourvideofilename;
     mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
     if (path == null || path.length() == 0) {
         Toast.makeText(HomeVideo.this, "File URL/path is empty",
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     } else {
         // If the path has not changed, just start the media player
         if (path.equals(current) && mVideoView != null) {
             mVideoView.start();
             mVideoView.requestFocus();
             return;
         }
         current = path;
         mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
         mVideoView.start();
         mVideoView.requestFocus();
     }
     mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

            Intent in =new Intent(HomeVideo.this,NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
            finish();
        }
     });
 }

     }
```

`xml` file like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<VideoView
android:id="@+id/video"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:keepScreenOn="true">
</VideoView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In manifest file

```
 <activity android:name=".HomeVideo" >
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>             

   </activity>
```

Comment: So i made a change ..                mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

            Intent in =new  Intent(HomeVideo.this,NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
            finish();
        }
     });

Comment: @Ramakrishna can u pls mention abt NextActivity.class

Comment: @JinjuJoseph After completion of video playing then new activity(that may be NextActivity or any our actiivty class) will starts.

Comment: @Ramakrishna, when i used a small video-3gp(77KB), its work fine. But i moved to a bgp file of 2.42 MB,it shows an error of can't play this video. Logcat is E/MediaPlayer(693): Error (1,-2147483648)
 D/VideoView(693): Error: 1,-2147483648

Comment: @JinjuJoseph See the video formats what are android native video player will supports

Comment: @JinjuJoseph See this link http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

**VideoViewExample** **.java**

```
package com.sample.VideoViewExample;

public class VideoViewExample extends Activity {
   private VideoView mVideoView;

   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
     mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.documentariesandyou));
     mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
     mVideoView.requestFocus();
   }
}
```

and add thid in the **XML** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <VideoView<br/>
       android:id="@+id/surface_view"
       android:layout_width="320px"
       android:layout_height="240px"/>
</LinearLayout>
```